# MacBook Pro keeps restarting

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, restart

Filevault is enabled.
Not able to login restarts again and again.
And already have run first aid.
Not able to reinstall macOS.
shows your computer restarted because of a problem.
MacBook Pro mid 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Macbook Pro mid 2012 have a problem of Sata Cable. You can try extract the disk/SSD and put it in a USB3 enclosure. Then you try boot on this external disk. If ok you have to change the Sata Cable. You can see this link : https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Cable+Replacement/10379